# App ID & bundle identifier: provisioning profile issues

Tags: ios, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'm working on an Ionic 3 project and just now getting around to setting up and testing notifications. I don't have prior native iOS development experience, so I've been following a few guides on how to get all the proper certificates, provisioning profiles, and other setup done correctly.

I have an Apple Developer account which I've added to Xcode and have so far been letting Xcode (version 8.3.3) handle signing automatically.

I'm implementing notifications as part of Mixpanel integration, so I've been following this guide: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ios-push-notifications. This guide is pretty complete- it walks the user through creating an app ID, adding push, creating & signing the required certs, creating a provisioning profile, and finally uploading those to Mixpanel. The entire process went fine.

When I connected my device in order to try and test push notifications, I started having issues building- I hadn't added the push notification Capability in Xcode, so I did that- however, when I did so, I started getting an error in the code signing config that my provsioning profile didn't include that capability. Weird, because in the details of my App ID on the Apple Developer site, I see that push notifications are enabled for development.

Upon closer inspection, I think the issue is that my App ID bundle identifier (on the Apple Dev site) and the bundle identifier in Xcode don't match. My App ID bundle identifier is:

```
<team_ID>.com.<domain>.app
```

But my bundle identifier in Xcode is:

```
com.<domain>.app
```

At the time I created the App ID, I thought the `<team_ID>` prefix was required for the bundle identifier in the App ID setup- but I don't think that's right. I see the prefix separately in the App ID info:

[image: App ID info]

Was this the wrong thing to do? The reason I got confused and added the team ID to my App ID bundle identifier was because my bundle identifier from Xcode (`com.<domain>.app`) wasn't allowed. The error I got when trying to use it while creating an App ID:

[image: error creating app id]

To be clear- I have no other App IDs in the Apple Developer profile with this bundle identifier.

I know this identifier should be available because I've been using it in Xcode before today, with the same signing identity. Why wouldn't I be allowed to use it to create an App ID- isn't the point that the bundle ID must be the same both in that and in Xcode?

The final confusing point here (to me) is that I decided to change the bundle identifier in Xcode to match that of my App ID (to confirm that, once they matched, building would work). After I did that, Xcode seemed to accept the new bundle identifier, but I get different build errors- and if I change my signing identity, the errors that show up in the signing config don't make sense- they reference a bundle identifier that isn't the one just above in Xcode:

[image: weird config error]

Specifically, why does the bundle identifier in the error not match what's set in the config at the top of the image? I've tried restarting Xcode and this still happens. At this point, I can't even build with Xcode if I remove the push capability- I get a mysterious `Apple Mach-O Linker (ID) error` which doesn't turn up much when googling.

Comment: The reason you can't create it is because some other apple developer account already has registered and is using the com.<domain>.app app ID.  Once a developer account is registered to use that app ID, you won't be able to add it on your account.  You are using automatic code signing, is it possible you had signed in initially with a different developer account.  If so, Xcode might have created / reserved your bundle ID on that other account.  I believe once it is registered to a developer account, it is reserved for 120 days.

Comment: Do you have a team account and a personal, free account?  Now that I'm looking at it, it appears you have the bundle ID registered under your free developer account (which won't work with Push Notifications), but likely are a developer of a team account that does not have the bundle ID reserverd (your personal account took that over through some actions you took when changing teams).  I would change your team to a paid developer account, change your bundle ID to something new, and it will likely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided answers and comments had good information, however, the only thing that worked for me was creating a new App ID that didn't conflict with the bundle identifier I had set in Xcode. I think the inclusion of my team prefix in my first App ID name played a large part in this usse, as I haven't seen that weird behavior since creating a new App ID with a normal bundle identifier.

Answer (score 1):

The provisioning profile you are using is configured for the bundle identifier in the error message you are receiving. To fix this you can either:

- Set the bundle identifier of your app to the one you see in the
  error message
- Create another provisioning profile with the bundle identifier you
  would like to use in your app

You will also need to add Push Notifications to your profile. Here are some instructions on how to do this:

1. Go to [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate) and for Mac apps, choose
   OS X from the pop-up menu on the left.
2. Under Identifiers, select App IDs.
3. Select the explicit App ID that matches the bundle ID.
4. A green circle followed by “Enabled” appears in the Push
   Notifications row and the Distribution column.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by point 1. Set the bundle identifier of my app in Xcode to the one I see in the error message? That was already the case- I attempted to use the bundle identifier from Xcode when creating the App ID and that's when I got the error message.

Comment: @dkhaupt try going here: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate and make sure your development profile has the "Push Notifications capability"

Comment: My provisioning profile does have "Push Notifications". I think this is related to the bundle identifier, and it also seems that whatever bundle identifier I have in Xcode is not usable when creating a new App ID. I think I'm going to need to create a new App ID, change my Xcode bundle identifier temporarily, then change it back once the App ID is created & has the proper setup

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the possible solutions above, if these do not work for you or if you are getting a build error that says something like:
'resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed'
then here is the solution that worked for me:

A: This is a security hardening change that was introduced with iOS 10, macOS Sierra, watchOS 3, and tvOS 10.

Code signing no longer allows any file in an app bundle to have an extended attribute containing a resource fork or Finder info.

To see which files are causing this error, run this command in Terminal:

$ xattr -lr

replacing  with the path to your actual app bundle.

Here's an example of this command in action:

$ xattr -lr Foo.app
/Applications/Foo.app: com.apple.FinderInfo:
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
You can also remove all extended attributes from your app bundle with the xattr command:

$ xattr -cr

Note that browsing files within a bundle with Finder's Show Package Contents command can cause Finder info to be added to those files. Otherwise, audit your build process to see where the extended attributes are being added.

[link to the original article in Apple developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1940/_index.html)